# Basic question about JLabel

Tags: java, swing, double, jlabel

Since i declare:

```
double total = 12.00;
```

why i cant put:

```
p1.add(jlbTotal= new JLabel (total));
```

Is there any way I can use to insert that total value?

Comment: 7 replies to 4 of your questions (one answer at least, of which has 5 up votes), and not a single correct answer among them?  I find that hard to understand.  Perhaps you should look to accept some of those answers.

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson this user is one of never returns answer, marked questions as answered and some other ***, crossposting, nor simple thanks, thank you that I don't have to laboriously learn, are you impatient like as she/he

Comment: <ot> and looks like as new "Darryl" cleanUp Java/Swing Forum before tomorow Labour Day </ot>

Answer (score 5):

`JLabel` does not take `doubles` in its constructors. You first need to convert your `double` to a `String`. For example:

```
new JLabel(String.valueOf(total));
```